# SwiftUI @StateObject nested @State value not updating

Tags: swiftui, state

I've run into an issue whilst trying to learn SwiftUI's binding and I'm struggling to understand why a @StateObject value can't be updated from its parent.

Here's what I've put together and I can open and close a `SheetView` successfully using it the .show enum but $isPresented still outputs as false, as if it's not being sent. $isPresented is being used inside `SheetView` on a button to close the `SheetView` from inside. How can I update isPresented from inside `ContentView` and inside `SheetView`?

```
class Presenter: ObservableObject {
enum Show: Equatable {
    case none, login, register
}

@Published var show: Show = .none
@State var isPresented: Bool = false

@ViewBuilder
func makeView() -> some View {
    switch show {
    case .none:
        EmptyView().onAppear {
            isPresented.toggle()
        }
    case .login:
        SheetView(isOpen: $isPresented) { // SheetView has a button which fails to close using isPresented.toggle() or isPresented = false
            LoginView()
        }
    case .register:
        SheetView(isOpen: $isPresented) {
            RegisterView()
        }
    }
}
}

struct ContentView: View {

@StateObject var presenter = Presenter()

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color("White")
        HomeView().environmentObject(presenter) // Has button which changes presenter to login via presenter.show = .login
        .overlay {
            switch presenter.show {
            case .none:
                EmptyView().onAppear {
                    presenter.isPresented.toggle() // Has no effect
                    presenter.show = .none
                }
            default:
                ZStack {
                    Color("Black").opacity(0.1).onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.interactiveSpring()) {
                            presenter.isPresented.toggle() // Has no effect
                            presenter.show = .none
                        }
                    }.transition(.opacity)
                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
    }.overlay {
        presenter.makeView()
    }
}

}
```

To include a MRE would take around 200 lines of code, hence the abridged version above. The main issue is how do you change a @State property from inside view which is already inside the @StateObject. SheetView needs to toggle $isPresented

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? Right now, there are missing types and this can't be copied/pasted into Xcode to run.

Comment: Added a footnote at the bottom to clarify the code above

Comment: We don't need to copy and paste it into Xcode to see that they're using `@State` in an `@ObservableObject`, and they're expecting `onAppear` to be run for an `EmptyView`.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two problems in your code.

First, SwiftUI discards `EmptyView` early enough in the rendering pipeline that it never “appears”. So an `onAppear` attached to an `EmptyView` will never be called. You can test it out in a playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(VStack {
    Text("hello")
        .onAppear { print("Text onAppear") }

    EmptyView()
        .onAppear { print("EmptyView onAppear") }
}.frame(width: 300, height: 300))
```

This prints `Text onAppear` but does not print `EmptyView onAppear`. In the context of the code you posted, you can replace `EmptyView` with `Color.clear`.

Second, `@State` only works when applied to a property of a `View`, a `ViewModifier`, a `Scene`, or an `App`. It doesn't work when applied to a property of an `ObservableObject`. You need to change `@State var isPresented` to `@Published var isPresented`.

But after you fix that, you won't be able to say `$isPresented` to get a `Binding<Bool>`. You could change `makeView` to take that `Binding` as an argument:

```
@ViewBuilder
func makeView(@Binding isPresented: Bool) -> some View {
    switch show {
    case .none:
        EmptyView().onAppear {
            isPresented.toggle()
        }
    case .login:
        SheetView(isOpen: $isPresented) { // SheetView has a button which fails to close using isPresented.toggle() or isPresented = false
            LoginView()
        }
    case .register:
        SheetView(isOpen: $isPresented) {
            RegisterView()
        }
    }
}
```

But at this point, it's probably better to move `makeView` into `ContentView` instead:

```
class Presenter: ObservableObject {
    enum Show: Equatable {
        case none, login, register
    }

    @Published var show: Show = .none
    @Published var isPresented: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var presenter = Presenter()

    @ViewBuilder
    func makeView() -> some View {
        switch presenter.show {
        case .none:
            Color.clear.onAppear {
                presenter.isPresented.toggle()
            }
        case .login:
            // SheetView replaced with Toggle to make this compile.
            Toggle("login", isOn: $presenter.isPresented)
        case .register:
            // SheetView replaced with Toggle to make this compile.
            Toggle("register", isOn: $presenter.isPresented)
        }
    }

    // body simplified because it's not important for this example.
    var body: some View { EmptyView() }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I caught the EmptyView issue after posting, good find :).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue removing `isPresented` and passing down a singleton of the same `Presenter`. So `Presenter.shared` inside contentView and inside Presenter. Then passed as a param on SheetView like: `SheetView(presenter: Presenter.shared)` - After this I could close SheetView from inside SheetView. Nice approach to allow multiple ways to close a Sheet both internally and externally.

Hope this helps anyone else on a related issue.